# A variation of the longest path problem

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

What about finding a path of maximum length in a given graph which may contain cycles, with the constraint that a vertex (or an edge) can be visited at most X (say 2 or 3) times ?

EDIT: X would be applicable globally, ie, the same X applies to all nodes of the graph.

What would an algorithm to solve this look like ?

Comment: How is $X$ given (e.g. binary or unary)? And is it global over the graph, or is there a different $X$ for each node?

Comment: It would be the same X over the graph.  But you made it even more interesting by suggesting the possibility to have a specific X for each node !

Answer (score 1):

What are you wondering about this problem? If $X$ is an input, it is obviously at least as hard as the longest path problem, since it contains the longest path problem as a special case ($X=1$). But I think, even for any fixed $X \geq 2$, you can reduce the longest path problem to your problem as follows:

Let $M$ be an upper bound on the length of the longest path in the graph. (For either weighted or unweighted version I believe $M$ is polysize.) For each vertex in the original graph, attach a cycle of length $M$. Then I am pretty sure (but it needs proving) that the maximum length walk that visits each vertex at most X times will be the longest path, plus $X-1$ walks around each cycle.

Comment: Thank you.  I stumbled last week on a puzzle that involved a longest path problem and it occurred to me that it could be made significantly harder if multiple visits of a node were allowed.  Then looking a bit around, I did not find anything in the literature about this variation, which seems interesting.  I initially shared your feeling about a potential solution, but I am not sure that cycles would in all cases be covered "in full" by the longest path.

Comment: @user1454590 when you say "I initially shared your feeling about a potential solution, but I am not sure that cycles would in all cases be covered "in full" by the longest path" what do you mean? I did not try to give an algorithm for your variant of the problem, but rather, show that it is "at least as hard" as the longest-path problem (so NP-hard) by showing that if you could solve this variant problem in polynomial time, then you can solve the longest path problem in polynomial time.

Comment: I guess I can only agree that this problem is at least NP-hard.